# Почему при выборе select всегда выдаёт 3500?

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementById('go').onclick = result;
var g = document.getElementById("mees").options.selectedIndex;
var n = document.getElementById("mes").options.selectedIndex;
var mes = document.getElementById("mes").options[n].value;
var cube = document.getElementById("nem").value;
var mees = document.getElementById("mees").options[g].value;

function result() {
  if (cube > 5) {
    result = mes * cube + mees * cube;
    documet.getElementById('resp').innerHTML = result;
  } else {
    result = mes * 5 + cube * mees
    document.getElementById('resp').innerHTML = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-white sticky-top">
      <ul style="background-color: #e7e7e7" class="nav justify-content-center p-4">
        <li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3"><a id="lel" href="#">НА ГЛАВНУЮ</a></li>
        <li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3"><a id="lel" href="#">РАСЧЁТ СТОИМОСТИ</a></li>
        <li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3"><a id="lel" href="#">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a></li>
        <li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3"><a id="lel" href="#">О НАС</a></li>
        <li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3"><a id="lel" href="#">КОНТАТНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ</a></li>
        <div class="navbar-brand ml-5">
          <a href="#"><img src="logo.png" width="80"></a>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form method="post">
    <select name="mes" id="mes">
      <option value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
      <option value="1100">Анна</option>
      <option value="370">Александровка</option>
      <option value="400">Бабяково</option>
      <option value="1100">Бобров</option>
      <option value="400">Берёзовка</option>
      <option value="650">Борщево</option>
      <option value="500">Ближние сады</option>
      <option value="800">Богданово</option>
      <option value="750">Большая приваловка</option>
      <option value="550">Боровое</option>
      <option value="950">Верхняя хава</option>
      <option value="500">Воля</option>
      <option value="650">Галкино</option>
      <option value="750">Горожанка</option>
      <option value="725">Гваздёвка</option>
      <option value="700">Графское</option>
      <option value="700">Гремячье</option>
      <option value="475">Дальние сады</option>
      <option value="700">Девицы</option>
      <option value="700">Желдаевка</option>
      <option value="475">Зайчья поляна</option>
      <option value="725">Землянск</option>
      <option value="750">Ивницы</option>
      <option value="625">Изумрудное</option>
      <option value="625">Кашира</option>
      <option value="525">Круглое</option>
      <option value="525">Кожевино</option>
      <option value="950">Конь-Колодезный</option>
      <option value="600">Колодезный</option>
      <option value="575">Каширский район,Посёлок им.Держ.</option>
      <option value="650">Кузиха</option>
      <option value="650">Левая Россошь</option>
      <option value="725">Латное</option>
      <option value="1200">Липецкая Усмань</option>
      <option value="525">Малышево</option>
      <option value="425">Масловский с/x</option>
      <option value="350">Масловка</option>
      <option value="675">Медъвежье</option>
      <option value="675">Медовка</option>
      <option value="600">Н.Воронеж</option>
      <option value="1000">Нижнедевицк</option>
      <option value="450">Новая Усмань</option>
      <option value="725">Новогремяченское</option>
      <option value="900">Нелжа</option>
      <option value="425">Нечаевка</option>
      <option value="725">Нижняя катуховка</option>
      <option value="350">Никольское</option>
      <option value="575">Орловка</option>
      <option value="525">Орлово</option>
      <option value="1200">Острогоржск</option>
      <option value="450">Отрадное</option>
      <option value="450">Отрожка</option>
      <option value="950">Панино</option>
      <option value="425">Парусное</option>
      <option value="525">Первое мая</option>
      <option value="525">Придонский</option>
      <option value="450">Петино</option>
      <option value="525">Подпольное</option>
      <option value="525">Подклетное село</option>
      <option value="575">Посёлок имени Дзержинского</option>
      <option value="525">Подгореое</option>
      <option value="675">Рамонь</option>
      <option value="625">Рожденственская Хава</option>
      <option value="425">Репное</option>
      <option value="550">Рогачёвка</option>
      <option value="550">Рыкань</option>
      <option value="325">с/х Масловский</option>
      <option value="800">Ступино</option>
      <option value="575">Староживотинное</option>
      <option value="800">Скляево</option>
      <option value="725">Семилуки</option>
      <option value="675">Стрелица</option>
      <option value="475">Сомово</option>
      <option value="425">Товарово</option>
      <option value="475">Тепличный</option>
      <option value="475">Теннистый</option>
      <option value="725">Углянец</option>
      <option value="475">Усмань</option>
      <option value="725">Хвощеватка</option>
      <option value="625">Хреновое</option>
      <option value="900">Хохол</option>
      <option value="1000">Хлевное</option>
      <option value="475">Чертовицы</option>
      <option value="525">Шуберское</option>
      <option value="550">Шилово</option>
      <option value="625">Ямное</option>
    </select>Место <input name="num" id="nem" type="number" min="1" step="1">М
    <sup><small>3</small></sup>
    <br>
    <select name="mees" id="mees">
      <option value="3150">Бетон m100</option>
      <option value="3250">Бетон m150</option>
      <option value="3400">Бетон m200</option>
      <option value="3580">Бетон m250</option>
      <option value="3480">Бетон m300</option>
      <option value="3950">Бетон m350</option>
      <option value="4300">Бетон m400</option>
      <option value="4450">Бетон m450</option>
      <option value="3700">Керамз.бетон m75</option>
      <option value="3800">Керамз.бетон m100</option>
      <option value="4000">Керамз.бетон m150</option>
      <option value="4100">Керамз.бетон m200</option>
      <option value="2420">Песк.бетон m100</option>
      <option value="2660">Песк.бетон m150</option>
      <option value="2900">Песк.бетон m200</option>
      <option value="3000">Песк.бетон m250</option>
      <option value="2420">Раств.цемент m100</option>
      <option value="2660">Раств.цемент m150</option>
      <option value="2900">Раств.цемент m200</option>
      <option value="3000">Раств.цемент m250</option>
    </select>Марка
  </form>
  <div class="sos"><button id="go" name="go" value="=">=</button>
    <div id="resp"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Переписываю калькулятор с `PHP`. Почему-то всё время выдаёт 3500, это если по дефолту оставить всё, но даже когда выбираешь `option`, то 3500.

Comment: Если задача решена, то закрывайте пожалуйста вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что вы в переменные помещаете один раз значение, а вызываемая функция должна работать с новыми.

```js
document.getElementById('go').onclick = result;


function result(){
var g = document.getElementById("mees").options.selectedIndex;
var n = document.getElementById("mes").options.selectedIndex;
var mes = document.getElementById("mes").options[n].value;
var cube = document.getElementById("nem").value;
var mees = document.getElementById("mees").options[g].value;

if(cube > 5){
result = mes * cube + mees * cube;
documet.getElementById('resp').innerHTML = result;
}
else {
 result = mes * 5 + cube * mees
 document.getElementById('resp').innerHTML = result;
}}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800" rel="stylesheet">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="res.js" defer></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">

 
 <div class="container-fluid">

 <div class="navbar-white sticky-top" ><ul style="background-color: #e7e7e7" class="nav justify-content-center p-4">
<li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3"><a id="lel"   href="#">НА ГЛАВНУЮ</a></li>
<li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3"><a id="lel"  href="#">РАСЧЁТ СТОИМОСТИ</a></li>
<li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3"><a id="lel"  href="#">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a></li>
<li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3"><a id="lel"  href="#">О НАС</a></li>
<li class="ml-1 py-2 px-3"><a id="lel"  href="#">КОНТАТНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ</a></li>
<div class="navbar-brand ml-5"><a href="#"><img src="logo.png" width="80"></a></div>

 </ul></div>
 </div>
 <form method="post">
       <select name="mes" id="mes">

            <option  value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
            <option  value="1100">Анна</option>
            <option  value="370">Александровка</option>
            <option  value="400">Бабяково</option>
            <option  value="1100">Бобров</option>
            <option  value="400">Берёзовка</option>
            <option  value="650">Борщево</option>
            <option  value="500">Ближние сады</option>
            <option  value="800">Богданово</option>
            <option  value="750">Большая приваловка</option>
            <option  value="550">Боровое</option>
            <option  value="950">Верхняя хава</option>
            <option  value="500">Воля</option>
            <option  value="650">Галкино</option>
            <option  value="750">Горожанка</option>
           <option  value="725">Гваздёвка</option>
           <option  value="700">Графское</option>
           <option  value="700">Гремячье</option>
           <option  value="475">Дальние сады</option>
           <option  value="700">Девицы</option>
           <option  value="700">Желдаевка</option>
           <option  value="475">Зайчья поляна</option>
           <option  value="725">Землянск</option>
           <option  value="750">Ивницы</option>
           <option  value="625">Изумрудное</option>
           <option  value="625">Кашира</option>
           <option  value="525">Круглое</option>
           <option  value="525">Кожевино</option>
           <option  value="950">Конь-Колодезный</option>
           <option  value="600">Колодезный</option>
           <option  value="575">Каширский район,Посёлок им.Держ.</option>
           <option  value="650">Кузиха</option>
           <option  value="650">Левая Россошь</option>
           <option  value="725">Латное</option>
           <option  value="1200">Липецкая Усмань</option>
           <option  value="525">Малышево</option>
           <option  value="425">Масловский с/x</option>
           <option  value="350">Масловка</option>
           <option  value="675">Медъвежье</option>
           <option  value="675">Медовка</option>
           <option  value="600">Н.Воронеж</option>
           <option  value="1000">Нижнедевицк</option>
           <option  value="450">Новая Усмань</option>
           <option  value="725">Новогремяченское</option>
           <option  value="900">Нелжа</option>
           <option  value="425">Нечаевка</option>
           <option  value="725">Нижняя катуховка</option>
           <option  value="350">Никольское</option>
           <option  value="575">Орловка</option>
           <option  value="525">Орлово</option>
           <option  value="1200">Острогоржск</option>
           <option  value="450">Отрадное</option>
           <option  value="450">Отрожка</option>
           <option  value="950">Панино</option>
           <option  value="425">Парусное</option>
           <option  value="525">Первое мая</option>
           <option  value="525">Придонский</option>
           <option  value="450">Петино</option>
           <option  value="525">Подпольное</option>
           <option  value="525">Подклетное село</option>
           <option  value="575">Посёлок имени Дзержинского</option>
           <option  value="525">Подгореое</option>
           <option  value="675">Рамонь</option>
           <option  value="625">Рожденственская Хава</option>
           <option  value="425">Репное</option>
           <option  value="550">Рогачёвка</option>
           <option  value="550">Рыкань</option>
           <option  value="325">с/х Масловский</option>
           <option  value="800">Ступино</option>
           <option  value="575">Староживотинное</option>
           <option  value="800">Скляево</option>
           <option  value="725">Семилуки</option>
           <option  value="675">Стрелица</option>
           <option  value="475">Сомово</option>
           <option  value="425">Товарово</option>
           <option  value="475">Тепличный</option>
           <option  value="475">Теннистый</option>
           <option  value="725">Углянец</option>
           <option  value="475">Усмань</option>
           <option  value="725">Хвощеватка</option>
           <option  value="625">Хреновое</option>
           <option  value="900">Хохол</option>
           <option  value="1000">Хлевное</option>
           <option  value="475">Чертовицы</option>
           <option  value="525">Шуберское</option>
           <option  value="550">Шилово</option>
           <option  value="625">Ямное</option>




        </select>Место <input name="num" id="nem" type="number" min="1" step="1">М
        <sup><small>3</small></sup>
        <br> <select name="mees" id="mees">

            <option  value="3150">Бетон m100</option>
            <option  value="3250">Бетон m150</option>
            <option  value="3400">Бетон m200</option>
            <option  value="3580">Бетон m250</option>
            <option  value="3480">Бетон m300</option>
            <option  value="3950">Бетон m350</option>
            <option  value="4300">Бетон m400</option>
            <option  value="4450">Бетон m450</option>
            <option  value="3700">Керамз.бетон m75</option>
            <option  value="3800">Керамз.бетон m100</option>
            <option  value="4000">Керамз.бетон m150</option>
            <option  value="4100">Керамз.бетон m200</option>
            <option  value="2420">Песк.бетон m100</option>
            <option  value="2660">Песк.бетон m150</option>
            <option  value="2900">Песк.бетон m200</option>
            <option  value="3000">Песк.бетон m250</option>
            <option  value="2420">Раств.цемент m100</option>
            <option  value="2660">Раств.цемент m150</option>
            <option  value="2900">Раств.цемент m200</option>
            <option  value="3000">Раств.цемент m250</option>

        </select>Марка


    </form>
    <div class="sos"><button id="go"   name="go" value="=">=</button><div id="resp"></div></div></div></body></html>
```